# Orientation change crash on listview sliding

Tags: android, listview, orientation, android-listview

I have a problem with a listview that crashes during orientation change. More specifically, it crashes only if the listview is "sliding" during orientation change. The layout are different in portrait/landscape and the views of the listview incorporate in landscape layout a custom view. It crashes because the findViewById on the custom view returns null. The strange thing is it only happens when sliding the listview!

I also tried to find a way to stop sliding the listview, but with no luck...

Thank you for any suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please add in manifest file android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" in your activites.

```
<activity android:name=".EventList" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" />
```

Comment: Nope. I need the activity to be destroyed and recreated on rotation, this prevents it. Btw, if I do this the app crash on EVERY screen rotation :)